# JRuby - Using SLF4J

Tags: java, jruby, slf4j

How do I get the equivalent of the following Java code (initializing a SLF4J logger) working in JRuby?

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Manager.class);
```

Let's say that my (working) example script looks like this:

```
def test(some_input)
     logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("SCRIPT");
     logger.error("Error...")
end
```

Because I'm a JRuby newbie I only got it working inside the method, and not with a `.class` in the `getLogger`.

So the questions are:

- How do I call `getLogger` using a `.class` as an argument in the JRuby code?
- How do I put the Logger object somewhere as a static ? I would like to avoid the `getLogger` every time I call the method.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Anyone? It shouldn't be that hard to understand my question, and to tell me whether it's possible or not, and how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to use `java_class` to get the "correct" class that is a (wrapped) `java.lang.Class` and not a ruby class as is with `java.util.Date.class` e.g. :

```
Java::OrgSlf4j::LoggerFactory.getLogger java.util.Date.java_class
```

as for storing it "statically" you could use class variables, but keep in mind that they are shared across the inheritance hierarchy, example :

```
@@logger = Java::OrgSlf4j::LoggerFactory.getLogger java.util.Date.java_class
```